# Modeling/sculpting hand

Tags: modeling, sculpting, sculpt

beginner doubt here!
I've been staring for this hand for a long time and have no idea how I could sculpt that.
Does anyone have any tips for me? I've been modeling for a really short time, so anything is helpful!
Thanks a lot in advance!!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: You'll easily find pictures of low-poly hands, but do you plan to animate? in that case don't model closed hands.

Comment: no, it's going to be static for a spark ar filter

Answer (score 4):

You can use your pictures as references, create a plane and subdivide it:

[image]

Extrude it up, extrude the fingers:

[image]

[image]

Rotate the front face or use the *Shear* tool, then continue to extrude and rotate:

[image]

[image]

Begin to work on the thumb:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, change the topology appropriately:

[image]

[image]