# How to build a hand out of a UV circle and Cylinder?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, draw-mode

I've tried to build this hand with uv circle and ciylinder but I just get nowhere... Can someone give me any tips oh how making those different shapes?

[image]

What I have so far is this shameless try... I'm planning in bevels + alt e to extrude into the shape.

[image]

It's really 'shapeless'...
[image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/z-SNS_98FkM?t=57

Comment: https://bfy.tw/Pf6A

Comment: yeah, I can't translate a normal hand to this reference I need to make... Mine doesn't have separate shapes for fingers and etc. It's almost like a sculpted hand.

Comment: It would help if you add an image of what you have so far...

Comment: hello Samantha, you've already asked the same question and I proposed an answer, if for some reason you're not satisfied with this answer tell it but don't ask several times the exact same question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201843/modeling-sculpting-hand

Comment: Duplicate of [Modeling/sculpting hand](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201843/modeling-sculpting-hand)